# Test reporting with Allure in JUnit 5

Tags: java, maven, gradle, allure, junit5

I am using Allure for test reporting of a JUnit 5 project. I am using both Maven and Gradle in the same project (for teaching purposes).

Regarding Maven, this is my [pom.xml](https://github.com/bonigarcia/mastering-junit5/blob/master/junit5-allure/pom.xml). Everything works as expected:

1. I run my tests with `mvn test` and the JSON files generated by Allure are stored on the folder `build\allure-results`
2. I managed to run launch the HTML report using `mvn allure:serve`

Regarding Gragle, this is my [build.gradle](https://github.com/bonigarcia/mastering-junit5/blob/master/junit5-allure/build.gradle). I have two problems here:

1. I would like to save the JSON file on `build/allure-results` when running my tests (`gradle test`) but I don't make it. The JSON files end in the default path, `allure-results` (in the root of the project).

   - Anybody knows how can be done?
2. I would like to launch the HTML report with Gradle, but I don't know how.

   - Is there any command equivalent to `mvn allure:serve` in Gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy some file or directory content into `build/allure-results` folder via Gradle, you might want to check the following example: https://github.com/sskorol/allure2-testng-report/blob/c89c6ba5cb22d812c5deec012014cc9e31310173/build.gradle#L38

Regarding your second question, please check the official plugin's page: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-gradle

Technically, you just need to download allure commandline (required only once) via:

```
gradlew allureReport
```

Then you can open report in browser via:

```
gradlew allureServe
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I must be doing something wrong since I don't make it. This is my [repository](https://github.com/bonigarcia/mastering-junit5/tree/master/junit5-allure). Any idea?

Comment: @BoniGarcía I'll check your repo and let you know.

Comment: @BoniGarcía see https://github.com/bonigarcia/mastering-junit5/pull/2 and comments. Talked to Allure devs. JUnit5 is not supported by gradle plugin at moment. But there's a feature request raised for that. For now you can use `allure-commandline` directly for report generation.

Comment: thanks for your help. Now it's clear what can be done at this moment.